# How to access files from other folders in Python?

Tags: python, import

I had a program like this:

```
def sig_input(audio):
    fs, data = read(audio)

    print(len(data))

sig_input('audio_file.wav')
```

But here I have a problem. My audio file is not in the same folder.
I grouped my audio files in one folder.

```
Project Folder
  | audio_folder
        | audio_file.wav
        | ...
  | main.py
```

My question is how do I access these audio files to main.py file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using this code:

```
def sig_input(audio):
    fs, data = read(audio)

    print(len(data))

sig_input('audio_folder/audio_file.wav')
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I have tried code like this, but it doesn't work because I wrote it wrong. I wrote it like this: `sig_input('/audio_folder/audio_file.wav')`. Thank you for the answer.